# Opencv Histogram Comparison

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Sample 1
[image: sample 1-1] [image: sample 1-2]

Score: -0.017456121638809906, Different: True

---

Sample 2
[image: sample 2-1] [image: sample 2-2]

Score: 0.36976129336917335, Different: True

I am comparing 2 sample sets.

1. The first sample set determined that it's different, which is correct.
2. The Second sample set determined that it's different, which is wrong. What I don't understand is that, both the images are almost black, but it returns a 0.369, which is below my threshold of 0.5.

How can I improve the result? Below is the code that I am using to produce the result

````
def compare_hist_correl(img1, img2):
    
    img1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    img2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    
    hist1 = cv2.calcHist([img1_gray], [0], None, [256], [0.0,255.0])
    hist2 = cv2.calcHist([img2_gray], [0], None, [256], [0.0,255.0])

    compare_dist_score = cv2.compareHist(hist1, hist2, cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL)
    
    if compare_dist_score < 0.5:
        return compare_dist_score, True
    else:
        return compare_dist_score, False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image1 = cv2.imread("sample1-1.png")
    image2 = cv2.imread("sample1-2.png")
    score, result = compare_hist_correl(image1, image2)
    print("Score: {}, Different: {}".format(score, result))
    
    image1 = cv2.imread("sample2-1.png")
    image2 = cv2.imread("sample2-2.png")
    score, result = compare_hist_correl(image1, image2)
    print("Score: {}, Different: {}".format(score, result))```
````

Comment: It matches because black matches and you have too much black. Try removing black from your histogram by setting its counts to zero before matching.

Comment: i am expecting sample 2 to be "False", or in other words, the value i am expecting should be greater than 0.5. Okay, let me remove the black and see the result